# Question on proving surjectivity of the map $f: P\mapsto \sigma(P)$ from set of partitions of a set finite $X$ to set of $\sigma$-algebras on $X$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

The starting place is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438537/different-partitions-generate-different-algebras?rq=1https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438537/different-partitions-generate-different-algebras?rq=1) on trying to show that the map $\sigma$ from the set of partitions $\mathcal{P}$ of a finite set $X$ to the set of algebras $\mathcal{A}$ on  $X$ defined by $\sigma: P\in \mathcal{P}\mapsto \sigma(P)\in \mathcal{A}$ ,where $\sigma(P)$ is the smallest algebra generated by the partition $P$, is injective.

The answer gives one proof of injectivity. I am interested in how to show surjectivity of the above map $\sigma$. So to be precise, I would like to show that given some algebra $A\in\mathcal{A}$, there exists a partition of $P$ such that $\sigma(P)=A$.

One idea is to define, for each $x\in X$, $A_x$ as the smallest set in $A$ containing $x$ and consider the collection $Y=\{A_x\}_{x\in X}$. I believe I can show that $X=\bigcup_{x\in A}A_x$ since $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in X} A_x$ and $A_x\subseteq X$, thus $\bigcup_{x\in X} A_x\subseteq X$. But I still need to show that $A_{x_1}$ and $A_{x_2}$ are disjoint for $x_1\neq x_2$ and that any set in $A$ can be generated from sets in the collection $Y$. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's cleaner to define the partition as consisting of the non-empty elements of $\mathcal{A}$ which are minimal with respect to inclusion, or equivalently which are irreducible with respect to intersection. In the language of Boolean algebra these are called *atoms*. Now it's clearer how to move forward: if $A, B$ are two atoms then $A \cap B$ is a subset of both $A$ and $B$. By the minimality of $A$ it must be empty or $A$, and in the latter case $A \subseteq B$, so by the minimality of $B$ we must have $A = B$ in this case. So distinct atoms are disjoint. Moreover

1. there must be at least one atom (because $\mathcal{A}$ is finite), and
2. taking the complement of such an atom and intersecting every other set in $\mathcal{A}$ with that complement, we conclude inductively that every $x \in X$ is contained in some atom.

So the atoms form a partition. Now, given an arbitrary subset $S \in \mathcal{A}$, we can consider its intersections $S \cap A$ with every atom. Again by minimality these intersections must either be empty or equal to $A$, and in the latter case $A \subseteq S$. Moreover every $s \in S$ is contained in some atom, as above. This gives that

$$S = \bigcup_{A \text{ atom}} (S \cap A).$$